# Run time to Theta Notation

Tags: runtime, big-o

After looking at the code:

```
for(i=n-1; i>=0; i-=2)
   for(j=15; j<100; j+=3)
      sum +=i+j
```

I would say that the run time for this in terms of Theta Notation to be Θ(n^2), as for there are two loops and const (i and j). Would this be correct?

Comment: Having two loops doesn't automatically mean that it is O(n^2). Look at the inner loop condition again - does it depend on anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I’ll put in another plug for that old asymptotic maxim of

> “When in doubt, work inside-out!”

Let’s take another look at that code:

```
for(i=n-1; i>=0; i-=2)
   for(j=15; j<100; j+=3)
      sum +=i+j;
```

Let’s begin with the innermost statement, the one that adds into the variable sum. That statement’s runtime is independent of any of the other variables here, so it does Θ(1) work. So let’s rewrite the code like this:

```
for(i=n-1; i>=0; i-=2)
   for(j=15; j<100; j+=3)
      do Theta(1) work
```

Now, let’s look at that inner for loop. Notice that this loop always runs the exact same number of times (around 30ish), regardless of the values of the other variables. That means that this loop runs a constant number of times and does a constant amount of work, and so the net effect of that loop is to do Θ(1) work. This is shown here:

```
for(i=n-1; i>=0; i-=2)
    do Theta(1) work
```

So now we’re left this this final loop. Here, we see that the work done depends directly and linearly on n. Specifically, this loop does Θ(n) iterations and does Θ(1) work per iteration, and so the total work done is **Θ(n)**.

Notice that it’s not the *number* of for loops that determines the runtime, but rather *what those loops are doing.* Counting the number of loops is a good way to get a rough estimate for the runtime, but the approach I illustrated above of working from the inside outward is more precise.